# C# Unable to get ErrorCode from SqliteException

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, error-handling, uwp

I am developing a Sqlite database driven UWP app in C#. In order to handle certain exceptions, I tried to simulate an error to see whether SqliteException was handled properly and to check what ErrorCode it returns on certain errors. Below is the code...

```
    public static bool testSqliteException()
    {
        SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=mydb.db");
        SqliteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(NoQuoteError)";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.NonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqliteException ex)
        {
            //I put a break here
            string err = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (command != null)
                command.Dispose();

            if (connection != null)
                connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The above is a function within a static DataAccessLayer class. Unfortunately, when I put a break in the place where I have commented and then type the following in the Immediate Window:

```
?ex.ErrorCode
```

It does not return a normal number as would SqlException.Number, and it is also returning the same number for any kind of error... i.e. -2147467259.
I also tried ex.SqliteErrorCode and that always returns 1.

What am I doing wrong, do I need to declare something for it to work? This is the only function in the entire class, as I am just getting started.

Comment: What is the error code that you expect to get?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield In SQL Server, you can run the following query and it shows you a different error number that one can use to handle SqlException, instead of relying on parsing the error message. ( SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages ). I was wondering whether Sqlite does the same thing as well?

Comment: On a broader note, my advice is to read up on SQLite. If you're used to SQLServer and have never used SQLite, they are decidedly NOT the same kind of animal. More to the point, what error code are you expecting in your test?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I have worked with Sqlite in an Android App, but had parse error message strings out there. You are right though, I am trying to approach this as I would do so for SQL Server. In that, the SqlException is able to differentiate a column not found in a table v/s a table not found using two different error numbers - 207 & 208 for "Invalid column name" and "Invalid object name". However, it does seem from the following link that the SqliteError code would always be 1 - Generic error in both those cases. https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html   Hope it was the other way around

Comment: @MarkBenningfield To answer your question directly, I am not sure what error number to expect, I was just hoping to differentiate an SqliteException due to table not found v/s some other reason using error numbers as opposed to having to parse error message strings, which may change with version or platform. Hence I tried to simulate an error, to get the error number or some property to differentiate different errors.

Comment: The SQLite error codes are pretty stable as far as that goes. For SQL syntax errors, you get error code 1, so yes, you'll have to parse the error messages if you want more detail.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Ok, I guess that's what I am stuck with. Can you confirm whether or not the SQL Syntax Error messages will always be the same irrespective of the SQLite version or device - Android, Windows Phone, Surface, Regular Laptop, etc.?

Comment: This comment thread is already getting too long, so to wrap it up, the SQLite error codes and messages are stable -- but, it depends more on the wrapper that you are using than on the SQLite engine itself.